# How to push and pop the details into the array in javascript based on the selection of cards?

Tags: javascript, django-templates

I am having 6 bootstrap cards in my web page where every card consists of details like id and content. When I clicked the card the details of the card should be pushed into the array and when I clicked the same card the details should be popped from the array.
My html page in django:

> 

```
<div class="row">
    {% for j in goal %}   
    <div class="col-4" onclick="getGoal({{j.id}})">
        <div class="card4 mt-3" id="room_{{j.id}}" style="width: 12rem; height:9rem;">
            <center>
            <div class="card-body">
                <p class="card-text mt-4" id="cont_{{j.id}}"><b>{{j.goal}}</b></p>
            </center>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> 
{% endfor %}
```

My js code is

```
var goal = []
function getGoal(id ,content){
    if (goal !== []) {
        for(var i=0; i<goal.length; i++){
            if(goal[i].id == id) {
                var index = goal.indexOf(goal[i])
                if (index !== -1) {
                    goal.splice(index, 1);  
                }
            }
        }
    }else {
        var data = {id: id, content: $("#cont_"+id).text()}
        var x = JSON.stringify(data)
        goal.push(x)
        console.log(goal)
    } 
}
var storedNames = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("goal"))
```

Is the JS code correct for my requirement?

Answer (score 0):

As you can see after adding indentations, you html code is not valide where do you close the center tag ? Else where / how do you call getGoal and why do you have the content parameter if you don't use it ?

Comment: i am getting the details of the card into the array the code is not wrong @Ip177 but when again selected the same card the details should pop that's the problem

Comment: I had used the content parameter to get the content of the card as the card details has id and content

Comment: the code is not valide if you don't close the center tag, all next tag is considering as child of the first center in this case for most of browser because they auto close at the end of the document all close that are not found

Comment: @Ip177 Yes I had closed the center tag but also not working

Answer (score 0):

```
var goal = []
function getGoal(id ){
  if (goal.length > 0) {
    let index = goal.findIndex(x=>x.id == id)
    if(index != -1){
        goal.splice(index, 1);  
    }
    else{
            var data = {id: id, content: $("#cont_"+id).text()}
            goal.push(data)
   }

   }else {
        var data = {id: id, content: $("#cont_"+id).text()}
        //var x = JSON.stringify(data)
        goal.push(data)
        console.log(goal)
    } 
  }
  var storedNames = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("goal"))
```

try It

Comment: its not working only the first card details are coming to array and even clicking the other card details are not coming.

Comment: goal array should be like this goal = [{id:1,content:"amit"},{id:2,content:"sinha"}]

Comment: yes I had checked and tried even only the first card details are coming into the array

Comment: Could you provide an working example with a feeded array ?

Comment: check once when you call the method getGoal what id is getting in getGoal using console.log(id)

Comment: var goal = [{id:1,content:"amit"},{id:2,content:"sinha"}]
    function getGoal(id){
    if (goal.length > 0) {
     let index = goal.findIndex(x=>x.id == id)
     if(index != -1){
      console.log("success")
      goal.splice(index, 1);  
     }

    }else {
     var data = {id: id, content: $("#cont_"+id).text()}
     var x = JSON.stringify(data)
     goal.push(x)
     console.log(goal)
    } 
    }
    getGoal(2)
    console.log(goal);

Comment: when i had used console.log(id) after function getGoal all the card ids are coming when selected

Comment: copy the code and paste in browser console . you will get the point

Comment: what ever i added in comment?

Comment: @ Amit I had pasted the code which you had kept in comment and got as success and the 1st is and content as amit is printed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204464/discussion-between-g-lakshmi-and-amit-sinha).